# Rails: how to pass params from one form to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here's my situation: I've got form that any visitor to the site can fill out. Of course, if s/he wants to submit it, they have to be a user.  So when they click "submit", they're taken to the sign up/in page. That's because I need a "user_id" before the data from that original form is saved.

What I would like to do is to take the params from the original form (params[:site]) and, instead of submitting them in a create action, I'd like to wait until the user has created an account.  This will allow me to avoid saving the site info to the database without a user id.

I could add some code to my site/create method, like this.

```
def create
  @site = Site.new(params[:site])   
  unless current_user?
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, sites_form_data: params[:site]
  end
  if @site.save
  # ...
end
```

But I'm not sure how to grab params[:site] once I've had the user create the account?

I'm using Devise for this project, so that may throw a wrench into the works.  I wonder if I'll have to overwrite the original devise controller, like this guy did: http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/04/overwrite-devise-registrations.html

I suppose I could also store the data in a cookie.  But I don't know when I'd access that cookie, extract the data, and save to the database.  After user creation, definitely.  But should it be a callback on the user model?  Where should it go?

I'd appreciate any suggestions or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just storing `:site` in the users session? This will persist across requests and mean that you dont have to keep such manual track of it.