# Best way to pass variables from one form to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to have a minimised form on the front page of my rails site which passes the values through to a full form (devise generated sign up form).

What I've currently done is a simple `form_tag` that uses a `get` method on `new_user_registration_path` (generated by devise). And then get the variables out of the url and populate the fields. But I feel this could be done a better way, perhaps with a variable and form_for?

I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585011/rails-how-to-pass-params-from-one-form-to-another) but would prefer to keep to Rails conventions, which seems to be variables, plus I'm not about user sessions.

I'm just learning Rails, could anyone help out?

Edit: added screenshots to help clarify use case hopefully:

Data is entered here, but as more is needed (password etc) before a user can be created

[image: small form]

it passes the entered variables to this full form on another page:

[image: full form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get the use case, but if you don't want to use sessions, to pass data from one form to another, you can set the variables in your controller like so:

```
@variable = params[:variable]
redirect_to :new_form
```

Then in your second form you can use a hidden field setting the @variable and just access it in params again.

Another option is using the [flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash)

Comment: Pretty cool, didn't know you could use flash to pass data around. But that would mean I'd need a controller for the smaller form right? Currently it's just a basic `form_tag` passing the variables.

Comment: You wouldn't need another controller, you could create another method in the same controller with a custom route. However, like I said before, the use case sounds odd can you give some more info? Is this like a "quick sign up button" where they enter one field and it takes them to the full form with that button populated?

Comment: I updated the question above for you with images, do they help? And yes, it's a quick sign up, but it leads to the full form with those 3 fields you entered populated and you complete the remaining.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I have to run out for a bit, but seeing the intent makes more sense. Agree with UX comments above, but understand better.

So if this was me, I would create a shared partial and show or hide the fields based on a variable (instead of creating two controllers or two places to post). 

Use a variable as described above to set values when needed. I can give a full answer when I get back if you're still stuck.

Comment: Makes sense, and make some of those non-required. Okay yep. Thank you for your help, and @digital-cake I'm going to try and convince them to strip down the form and only have one. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [`Wicked`](http://rubygems.org/gems/wicked) gem. Its makes easier for you to create multi-step forms. so I think It would help you in this case as well.

> Use wicked to make your Rails controllers into step-by-step wizards.
>   To see Wicked in action check out the example Rails app or watch the
>   screencast.
>
> Many times I'm left wanting a RESTful way to display a step by step
>   process that may or not be associated with a resource. Wicked gives
>   the flexibility to do what I want while hiding all the really nasty
>   stuff you shouldn't do in a controller to make this possible. At it's
>   core Wicked is a RESTful(ish) state machine, but you don't need to
>   know that, just use it.

For more details, see:

- [wicked on github](https://github.com/schneems/wicked)
- [RailsCasts on Creating Multi-step Wizard Style forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked)

Comment: Awesome gem I'm keeping filed, but seems overkill for this case? I just need to pass 3 fields to one other form.